# How to open console2 (or any other exe) through the explorer location bar

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-registry, console2

Often I want to do something in CMD or Python with files in a particular folder so I open the folder, click on the location bar and type "cmd" or "python" (then hit Enter) and, respectively, CMD or the Python terminal opens with that folder as there current working directory.

I'm trying to switch to using Console2 (mainly for copy/paste ease) and I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same.  If I type "console" (which is the run command I set up) in a location bar, explorer thinks this must an internet address and opens my web browser to the address "console/".

Note:
I know how to add (and have added) right-click context menus, but I'd prefer to type "console" into the location bar as that's my current habit.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think the reason that cmd (and possibly python) works is that the executables are in your PATH. Is this the case for console as well?

Comment: @Crippledsmurf I added the folder that Console.exe is in to PATH and now it opens from the location bar as desired.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as Crippledsmurf suggested in a comment, was simply that I needed to add the directory that Console.exe is in to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

ConEmu has "Default terminal" feature. It will handle all console applications regardless of the way you've start them.