# Part 2: How to open console2 (or any other exe) through the explorer location bar

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, console2

I'd like to open Consolez from the address bar in explorer, which is easy enough, but the problem is, it's pointless to do it if want ConsoleZ to start in explorer's current directory. I've tried some command line options, but I can't get anything to work. Does anyone know how this is done?

This is a continuation of [this thread,](https://superuser.com/questions/886570/how-to-open-console2-or-any-other-exe-through-the-explorer-location-bar/887154#887154) which I can't comment n becauseI have 0 points...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you've set startup directory for your tab in Console settings.